# AnyType array cast to specific instance of an array

Tags: arrays, generics

this is my method signature

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> int binarySearch(AnyType[] a, AnyType x)
```

and I need to declare a as an array of type Rectangle. but I'm getting an error when I do

```
Rectangle[ ] rect = (Rectangle) a;
```

is there a way I can set the AnyType array a equal to an array of type Rectangle?